# SQL Command to add a fields, or field with Formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, field

I am trying to add a field call MaxDate (the latest DOS Date from DOS column in table) which I have in code so it can show up in output but it is not working.    my SQL Query is as follows.

**CODING**

```
Select distinct t.RECORD_ID, t.SEQ_NO, t.CLAIM, t.HIC_NO as HICN_MBI ,t.ID, DOS, t.ERROR_1
 from Sandbox.dbo.XYZ t
 inner join (
  select CLAIM, max(DOS) as MaxDate
  from Sandbox.dbo.XYZ
  Group by CLAIM 
) tm on t.CLAIM = tm.CLAIM and t.DOS = tm.MaxDate
 where RECORD_ID='inf' OR RECORD_ID='REJ'
 and ERROR_1 in ('004',
                    '001',
                    '002',
                    '003')
```

OUTPUT RETURN columns
will show the columns but the maxdate will not appear in output

```
RECORD_ID  SEQ_NO  CLAIM  HICN_MBI ID DOS ERROR_1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the code you are using is not selecting the `maxdate` is because in the select statement you have not selected `maxdate` it is inside the table alias `tm`. I have added `tm.maxDate` in the select and this should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.RECORD_ID
    ,t.SEQ_NO
    ,t.CLAIM
    ,t.HIC_NO AS HICN_MBI
    ,t.ID
    ,DOS
    ,t.ERROR_1
    ,tm.MaxDate
FROM Sandbox.dbo.XYZ t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CLAIM
        ,max(DOS) AS MaxDate
    FROM Sandbox.dbo.XYZ
    GROUP BY CLAIM
    ) tm ON t.CLAIM = tm.CLAIM
    AND t.DOS = tm.MaxDate
WHERE RECORD_ID = 'inf'
    OR RECORD_ID = 'REJ'
    AND ERROR_1 IN (
        '004'
        ,'001'
        ,'002'
        ,'003'
        )
```

Comment: I've added in code formatting, but this could be improved by adding some explanation as to what's happening and how it addresses the question.

Comment: thank you!!!  It worked.  I appreciate it.   I just started a job in which we are using both SQL and SAS.   They brought me in because of my healthcare and informatics knowledge.  I am taking some classes but these are live projects with a two day turnaround.  I know this is basic but it helps me a lot.  This site is a goldmine of experts that have saved me.

Comment: You are welcome. It is difficult to learn any coding in the initial stages. It is always better to share your thoughts and questions with people and there by understand the problem.

Comment: I found the answer is correct, why the vote is negative here? Up vote from me

Comment: Not sure why the answer was flagged negative earlier thanks Arif